# I need a very simple way to retrieve a number with API

Tags: python-2.7

https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD/last

As you can see, this URL returns a single number.  I just want to retrieve that number and store it in a variable for my current python script (v 2.7.3)

I figured out how to do it.  Check below.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        import json
        import urllib2

        data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD/last'))
        print data
```